# What are the commands to get and set the contrast Gamma setting of raster image displays?

Tags: dm-script

I am trying to overlay two images, but I also want to be able to pass the gamma from each of the images to the final image. I know that one can get and set contrast limits as well as adjust the intensity transformation (ITT), but I have not found commands to access the Gamma value.

Am I just missing something? It would be helpful to be able to set the gamma for both images separately before overlaying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The according commands are

`Number ImageDisplayGetGammaCorrection( ImageDisplay imgDisp )`

and

`void ImageDisplaySetGammaCorrection( ImageDisplay imgDisp, Number gamma )`

and they are used like in the following example:

```
image img1:=RealImage("test1",4,256,256)
img1 = icol
ShowImage(img1)
img1.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplaySetGammaCorrection(0.6)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Is there a place where I can search for these functions? There didn't seem to be anything in the help files about this...

Comment: @Michael Yes, the help-file does not always cover all (new) commands. They appear over time... As for other places to search for these things: I guess you know the Script Database and other resources linked from the Gatan webpage (section "Scripting")? But generally, I think asking here might be the best guess - and it helps others searching for the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll definitely ask some more questions as I continue to learn.